# AWS SAM specify zip file name and use versioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I have different projects running in AWS, some of which use cloudformation, and others use SAM (serverless application model). With cloudformation deploys, I follow a build once, deploy anywhere model. I build the zip(s) on merge to trunk, and push it to s3. However, I use the same zip, just different versions for various environments (the bucket has versioning enabled, and I track code with tags and metadata and get rid of old versions with lifecycle policies). I’d like to follow the same flow for my SAM pipelines.

However, it seems that while I can specify a s3 prefix, I cannot specify the full name, and I may not be able to force the code to upload to the same bucket with the same name every time. Is this possible in Sam with some option I haven’t discovered?

For example, if I have a lambda that builds to “handlePayment” I want all versions of the zip to upload to the same s3 bucket with the same name “handlePayment” and to handle the versioning with tags/metadata. It is also important to note that with cloudformation, I can host the code in a separate AWS account, but I don’t see that option in SAM either.

Comment: Do `--s3-prefix` and `--s3-bucket` from `sam package` work for you?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-package.html